# problem with arabxetex

Tags: arabic

please help me i can't resolve this problem 
the problem is character `_t`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs ,tabularx,multirow}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic , Scale=1.5]{Nazli}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|r  ||||X|||| r |}
\toprule
\textarab{AlmdT AlzmnyT : sA`tAn} & \centering \textarab{{\LARGE Al-'imt.hAn Al|m|.hly Al|m|w.hd }} & \textarab{'i`dAdyT `bd Alkrym Alx.tAby } \\
\textarab{AldwrT : $II$}& \centering   \textarab{\Large{fy m|AdT AlryA.dyAt}}&\textarab{nyAbT tAwryrt} \\
\textarab{Alm`Aml : $3$} & \centering  \textarab{AlsnT Al_tAl_tT  'i`dAdy} & \textarab{dabdw} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the `tabularx` necessary for the example? Can you reduce to a minimum that still describes the issue?

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with a font which people are already likely to have or which they can download if necessary? (Only ask people to download it if it is really essential to reproduce the issue because asking that will reduce the number of people prepared to try to help you.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `tabularx` reads the whole contents of the table for typesetting it a couple of times. Doing so disrupts the working of `\textarab` that normally changes the category code of `_` so to become a “letter”, but it can't in this case, because the text has already been read in (and tokenized).

A possible workaround is to make `_` math active and behave like a printable character outside math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs ,tabularx,multirow}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic , Scale=1.5]{Scheherazade}

\begingroup\lccode`~=`_ \lowercase{\endgroup\let~\sb}
\AtBeginDocument{\mathcode`\_=\string"8000 \catcode`\_=12 }


\begin{document}
$x_{1}\ne x_{2}$

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{r X r}
\toprule
\textarab{AlmdT AlzmnyT : sA`tAn} &
  \LARGE\centering \textarab{Al-'imt.hAn Al|m|.hly Al|m|w.hd} &
  \textarab{'i`dAdyT `bd Alkrym Alx.tAby } \\
\textarab{AldwrT : $II$}&
  \Large\centering \textarab{fy m|AdT AlryA.dyAt} &
  \textarab{nyAbT tAwryrt} \\
\textarab{Alm`Aml : $3$} &
  \centering \textarab{AlsnT Al_tAl_tT 'i`dAdy} &
  \textarab{dabdw} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

I added a formula to show that `_` still works in math mode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with the  symbole of `underscore` inside `tabularx` environment , what you need to do is to change the category of the underscore symbole  with `\catcode`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs ,tabularx,multirow}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic , Scale=1.5]{Amiri}

 \catcode`\_=11  % change the category of underscore to a lettre

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|r  ||||X|||| r |}
\toprule
\textarab{AlmdT AltzmnyT : sA`tAn} & \centering \textarab{\LARGE Al-'imt.hAn Al|m|.hly Al|m|w.hd } & \textarab{'i`dAdyT `bd Alkrym Alx.tAby } \\
\textarab{AldwrT : $II$}& \centering   \textarab{\Large fy m|AdT AlryA.dyAt}&\textarab{nyAbT tAwryrt} \\
\textarab{Alm`Aml : $3$} & \textarab{AlsnT Al_tAl_tT  'i`dAdy} & \textarab{dabdw} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

 \catcode`\_=8  % return the category of the underscore


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

i can't resolve this problem please help

\documentclass[oneside]{article}

\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=0cm,left=1cm,right=1cm]{geometry}

\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.5]{Andalus}

%-----------\qst[bareme,bar=...]{......}----------------------%

\makeatletter
\define@cmdkey[EX]{qst}{bar}{}
\define@boolkey[EX]{qst}{bareme}[true]{}
\presetkeys[EX]{qst}{bar= ,bareme=false}{}
\newcommand{\qst}[2][]{
\setkeys[EX]{qst}{#1}

\ifEX@qst@bareme
    \ifdim  pt  < 2 pt
\begin{arab}
$-\arabic{k}$  #2 \marginpar{ \cmdEX@qst@bar}
\end{arab}
    \else
\begin{arab}
$-\arabic{k}$  #2 \marginpar{ \cmdEX@qst@bar }
\end{arab}
    \fi
\else
\begin{arab}
$-\arabic{k}$ #2
\end{arab}
\fi
\stepcounter{k}
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\qst{`ml mA yly  Al-ll_ah 'akbr mmT: }
\qst[bareme, bar=2]{`ml mA yly : }
\qst{`ml mA yly : }
\qst{`ml mA yly Al------ll_a----------h: }
\qst{`ml mA yly : }

\end{document}